# How Exceptions are handled while designing DataLayer or any other layered architecture

Tags: design-patterns, api, exception, data-layers

I am creating a data access layer where I want to handle exceptions that should be catched by Business layer with clear idea of the source of exception. 
I am doing something like this..

**EDIT**

```
private void OpenConnection()
        {
                if (ConnectionState.Closed == _connection.State)
                    _connection.Open();
        }
```

In the above given code i know an reason for exception. And want to throw it to be handled at BL to display message.

But I am using this function in DL only with some other line of codes.

```
protected DataTable GetDataTable(string Query)
 {
     DataTable dt =new DataTable();
     SqlCommand cmd = InitializeCommand(Query);

     SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     try
     {
         OpenConnection();
         adp.Fill(dt);
         CloseConnection(true);
         return dt;
     }
     catch (SqlException ex)
     { throw ex; }
     finally
     {
         adp.Dispose();
         cmd.Dispose();
     }
 }
```

Now if an exception occurs in `OpenConnection()` while trying to open the connection then the application crashes at the line `throw ex` in OpenConnection itself while I was expecting it to return exception.
How should I handle this issue.
Moreover extending my question in the second function `GetDataTable` if an exception occurs what kind of exception should be thrown with same details as occured at this point and how.
I only know this way but this is a wong way i think.

```
throw new ApplicationException(ex.message,ex.innerexception)
```

**Edit**

Suppose Connection to server losts or I am using wrong connection string. Now I use  GetDataTable function from BL. Where will exception occur and where should I handle it ?
I want to know the problem that occured in DL. Considering BL dont know the code of DL

Comment: In your first code sample, why use `try{}catch{}` if all you will do is re-throw the exception? Just remove all of that.

Comment: @Oded: I dont know exactly what should be done. If I remove try catch from first block will it get handled at the functions where i am using it.

Comment: and how is that different from what is happening now? You are re-throwing the exception, and it gets handled at functions that are using it...

Comment: @Oded: Plz check edit and give some helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you can do.

You can have different `try` blocks, and throw new exceptions according to where you had the problem:

```
 try
 {
     OpenConnection();
     adp.Fill(dt);
 }
 catch (SqlException ex)
 { throw new SqlException("Could not open/populate", ex); }
 finally
 {
     adp.Dispose();
     cmd.Dispose();
 }

 try
 {
     CloseConnection(true);
     return dt;
 }
 catch (SqlException ex)
 { throw new SqlException("Could not close connection", ex); }
 finally
 {
     adp.Dispose();
     cmd.Dispose();
 }
```

Comment: Since SqlException an not be explicitly thrown like this. throw new SqlException(""), What should be used instead. Is it recommendable to use multiple try catch within same function.

Comment: @Shantanu Gupta - This is just illustrative of what you _can_ do. You could create your own exception classes that are more descriptive (`OpenConnectionException`, `CloseConnectionException`) and throw those.

Comment: Suppose I have create a OpenConnectionException and throws it in OpenConnection Function than will it be possible to handle it at BL with some general exception say DataLayerException and it will provide me details where exception actually occured.

Comment: @Shantanu Gupta - Yes. When you throw an exception, it will have these details. You should create your own `DataLayerException` and have the others inherit from it.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to remove the catch and rethrow since this will destroy the stack trace of the exception.  You can have a try with no catch since you are throwing an exception anyway.  In this way you can preserve the stack trace and still use the finally:

```
protected DataTable GetDataTable(string Query)
 {
     DataTable dt =new DataTable();
     SqlCommand cmd = InitializeCommand(Query);

     SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     try
     {
         OpenConnection();
         adp.Fill(dt);
         CloseConnection(true);
         return dt;
     }
     finally
     {
         adp.Dispose();
         cmd.Dispose();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create a custom exception class say DataLayerExcetpion and from there throwing ApplicationException with message and innerException sent from here.

Comment: Yes you could, but would it help in debugging later on?  I prefer a simple approach so that you know where the exception took place and the message from the exception itself.  Extra information isn't really needed.  But I do prefer to keep things simple.